# Tool for determining TCP configurations

Tags: networking

Looking for a tool that can determine TCP settings of a server.

I was just evaluating whether to enable SACK and thought I might like to check what others are doing, but couldn't figure out a way.

Comment: Too generic. You can do that with `netstat` if you want

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani If that works, great. How do I use `netstat` to determine if, say, the `stackexchange.com` server can use SACK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see, you are looking for the SACK Panic vulnerability.

In this case you can use:

- **Wireshark**: through [this guide](https://pentest-tools.com/blog/how-to-detect-sack-panic-vulnerability-wireshark/)
- **tcpdump**: through this [command](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/What+You+Need+To+Know+About+TCP+SACK+Panic/25046/) `tcpdump -i eth0 -n 'ip[8]<65 and tcp[13]&0x2f=2'  | grep 'sackOK'`

Next time for security questions post on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't got that far as I was just initially curious to see what others are doing.